# Create an Excel file with the name of sheets taken from a vector

Tags: r, excel, export-to-excel

Starting from the vector:

```
vector <- c("alfa", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon")
```

I would like to create an Excel file with the name of sheet1 = alfa, the name of sheet2 = beta, etc.

Is there a way?

Actually, I need to export multiple dataframes in an .xlsx format and I use the package "writexl" and these instructions:

```
  sheets <- list("sheet1Name" = dataframe1, "sheet2Name" = dataframe2)
  write_xlsx(sheets, "data.xlsx")
```

but I have to write the "sheet*Name" manually, and I have more than 100 sheets...
For this reason I would like to take their names from a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could just use `setNames` or assign the `names` with the `vector` values

```
sheets <- mget(ls(pattern = '^dataframe\\d+$'))
names(sheets) <- vector
```